# Align 2 divs with 1 div under

Tags: html, css

I got two divs next to each other using a wrapper and the following code:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 15px;
}
#first {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    color: white;
}
#second {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1F1F1F;
  color: white;
}
```

And under those two divs I got a div with a width of 70% with the following code:

```
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
```

but it seems like the one div with 70% is bigger than the two divs next to each other because the div has a `padding` of 15px. How do I make the two divs aligned with the one div without removing the `padding` from the big div?

See image:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/483988757360410628/723158686872240188/unknown.png

Comment: Use [box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for your elements

Answer (score 1):

Use `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to include `padding` and `borders` in all widths (instead of adding them to the widths), and also consider/calculate the `margin`s in the overall sum, which are *not* included by `box-sizing: border-box;`.